# 'dateClick' does not exist in type 'CalendarOptions' [fullcalendar] v6

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

this is the code i use in angular

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin ],
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev today next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
    },
    weekends: true,
    events: [],
    locale:'vi',
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    selectable: true,
    editable: true,selectMirror: true,
    select: function(info) {
      alert('selected ' + info.startStr + ' to ' + info.endStr);
      console.log("mạnh đã ở đây")
    },
    dateClick: function(arg){
      alert('date click');
    }
```

> Error : Type '{ plugins: PluginDef[]; initialView: string;
> headerToolbar: { left: string; center: string; right: string; };
> weekends: true; events: undefined[]; locale: string; dayMaxEvents:
> true; selectable: true; editable: true; selectMirror: true; select:
> (info: DateSelectArg) => void; dateClick: (arg: any) => void; }' is
> not assignable to type 'CalendarOptions'.   Object literal may only
> specify known properties, and 'dateClick' does not exist in type
> 'CalendarOptions'.ts(2322)

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? please

Comment: My problem was solved as follows:
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Glad to see you found the answer. Will recommend writing it as the answer as it may help for future readers. You may read [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20a%20question,on%20a%20Stack%20Exchange%20site.)  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was solved as follows:

```
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add all code to your answer as _text_, not a picture - people cannot easily copy your answer to re-use it, when it's like this! There is no reason not to provide text, it's a simple as copying and pasting! If you [edit] it appropriately, you can have my upvote. Thanks.